# same name for multiple inputs

Tags: php

I have a form... where I have to use the same name for fields for every product that I have on the form.

PartNo, Item and Price, this cannot vary if I want to add multiple items with one order button. The example code below works for adding multiple items to the cart with Cart32's shopping cart software. I would like to know how they use the same name like PartNo for many items, and are able to retrieve all the values for that field.

I tried writing my own page to receive the input, and for the life of me, I cannot get multiple items for any of the repeated field like PartNo, Qty and Price. I have tried $_REQUEST, $_POST and $_GET and I only get the last value so it is not a case issue.

here is a stripped down example.

```
<FORM name ='x' METHOD="post" ACTION="https://www.cart32.com/cart32.ex…
<!-- item 1 -->
<div id'=x'>
#1 | desc1 | $27.99 Qty: <input type='text' size='3' name='Qty' value='0'>
<input type=hidden name='PartNo' value='11'>
<input type=hidden name='Item' value='product1'>
<input type=hidden name='Price' value='27.99'>
</div>


<!-- item 2 -->
<div id'=x'>
#2 | desc2 | $7.99 Qty: <input type='text' size='3' name='Qty' value='0'>
<input type=hidden name='PartNo' value='11'>
<input type=hidden name='Item' value='product1'>
<input type=hidden name='Price' value='7.99'>
</div>

<div><input type='submit' value='Order'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: use `name=PartNo[]` and retrieve in PHP via an array `var_dump($_POST['PartNo'])`  `$_POST['PartNo'][0] $_POST['PartNo'][1]` etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding multiple inputs to file php form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763530/adding-multiple-inputs-to-file-php-form-submit)

Comment: If for some reason you can't do what Michael suggests (which is the right answer) then it is theoretically possible to roll your own parser for the body of the message that will handle the data as is, but it is a huge PITA so try that first.

Comment: maybe `name = "myInput[][PartNo]"` would be more convenient

Answer (score 2):

If you append [] to your form field names, PHP will take those fields and turn them into an array, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="field[]" value="first" />
<input type="text" name="field[]" value="second" />
<input type="text" name="field[]" value="third" />
```

would produce the following $_POST structure:

```
$_POST = array(
    'field' => array(
         0 => 'first',
         1 => 'second',
         2 => 'third',
    )
);
```

The alternative is to append incrementing numbers to each field name, as you duplicate the existing field sets for each new block. This provides a nice separation between blocks and allows you guarantee that related fields have the same numerical tag, but it does complicate processing.

[Adding multiple inputs to file php form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763530/adding-multiple-inputs-to-file-php-form-submit)